# Is it possible to compose C# source generators?

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators

Can I have a source generator that generates code based on another source generated code? In other words, can we compose source generators?

Currently I'm doing this by splitting projects. I have ProjectA.csproj which has FirstSourceGenerator.csproj. Then I have ProjectB.csproj (which references ProjectA.csproj) with SecondSourceGenerator.csproj. This works, but I want to have just one project.

I know that I can generate all the code in one round. But I'm taking advantage of the fact that the generated code is turned into symbols. It is much easier for me to work with symbols than my own constructs. Also, I have the syntax checked by the compiler after each round, so I know that the previous round was successfully compiled.

Comment: From the [design document](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.md) "each generator will see the same input compilation, with no access to files created by other source generators."